# Filtering data based on props passed from adjoining element

Tags: reactjs

The idea is to select a district from the District dropdown and populate the Ward dropdown with values of that district's respective `ward` keys from the JSON stored in `dummy_data.json`. My plan was to pass the selected value from the `SearchBox` component as a prop to the `WardNo` component and then filter out the data based on the prop or the selected value. For example, If I selected Kolkata from the District dropdown, the Ward dropdown should have 6,7, and 8. Similarly, Hooghly should print 9,10, and 11, and likewise, Malda has to have the values 12,13, and 14. The problem right now is that no matter what option I select, the Ward Dropdown remains empty. Below is a screenshot of both the dropdowns, the JSON, and the codes for the `SearchBox` and `WardNo` components. Can someone please point out what I've done wrong here?

[image]

The JSON data

```
[
    {
        "district": "Kolkata",
        "ward_no": [
            {
                "ward": "6",     //These are the ward values that I'm after
                "grievance": [
                    {}........
                ],
                "status": "open"
            },
            {
                "ward": "7",
                "grievance": [
                    {}........
                ],
                "status": "open"
            },
            {
                "ward": "8",
                "grievance": [
                    {}........
                ],
                "status": "open"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "district": "Hooghly"
        "ward_no": [
            {
                "ward": "9",
                "grievance": [
                    {}........
                ],
                "status": "open"
            },
            {
                "ward": "10",
                "grievance": [
                    {}........
                ],
                "status": "open"
            },
            {
                "ward": "11",
                "grievance": [
                    {}........
                ],
                "status": "open"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "district": "Malda"
        "ward_no": [
            {
                "ward": "12",
                "grievance": [
                    {}........
                ],
                "status": "open"
            },
            {
                "ward": "13",
                "grievance": [
                    {}........
                ],
                "status": "open"
            },
            {
                "ward": "14",
                "grievance": [
                    {}........
                ],
                "status": "open"
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

SearchBox component(which renders the District dropdown)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import './search.css';
import { IoMdArrowDropdown } from 'react-icons/io';
import { GoTriangleUp } from 'react-icons/go';
import dummyData from '../../../json_data/dummy_data.json';
import WardNo from "../ward_no/ward_no";
import Category from "../category/category";

const SearchBox = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [dropDownValue, setDropDownValue] = useState(null);

    console.log(`district: ${dropDownValue}`);

    const onSelect = (value) => {
        setDropDownValue(value);
        setOpen(!open);
        <WardNo dropDownValue={dropDownValue}></WardNo>    //This is where I'm passing the prop from
    };


    return (
        <div className="box_district">
            <div className="district_caption">District</div>
            <div className="block_drop">
                <div className="district_dropdown">
                    <div className="search_box">            
                        {dropDownValue === null ? "Enter District" : dropDownValue}                     
                    </div>
                    <div className="drop_icon" onClick={() => setOpen(prev => !prev)}>
                        {open ? <GoTriangleUp size={"22px"} /> : <IoMdArrowDropdown size={"30px"} />}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={open ? "open_options" : "options"}>
                    {dummyData.map((districts) => <div className="select_options" onClick={() => onSelect(districts?.district)}>
                        {districts.district}
                        {console.log(`selected district : ${dropDownValue}`)}
                    </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default SearchBox;
```

WardNo Component(This renders the WardNo dropdown)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import './ward_no.css';
import { IoMdArrowDropdown } from 'react-icons/io';
import { GoTriangleUp } from 'react-icons/go';
import dummyData from '../../../json_data/dummy_data.json'

const WardNo = (props) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [wardNumber, setWardNumber] = useState(null);
    var filteredData = dummyData.filter(value => value.district === props);

    const onSelect = (value) => {
        setWardNumber(value);
        setOpen(!open);
    }

    return (
        <div className="ward_no">
            <div className="ward_caption">Ward No</div>
            <div className="ward_block">
                <div className="ward_dropdown">
                    <div className="ward_box">
                        {wardNumber === null ? "Enter Ward Number" : wardNumber}
                    </div>
                    <div className="ward_dropIcon" onClick={() => setOpen(prev => !prev)}>
                        {open ? <GoTriangleUp size={"25px"} /> : <IoMdArrowDropdown size={"30px"} />}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={open ? "ward_option" : "ward_option_block"}>
                    {filteredData.map((value, key) => (
                        value.ward_no.map((ward_value, ward_key) => <div className="ward_options" key={ward_key} onClick={() => onSelect(ward_value.ward)}>
                            {ward_value.ward}
                        </div>)
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default WardNo;
```

Comment: Whatever you want to render that should be inside return function. So place your `Ward` component inside return function

Comment: @Gnanavel But will that not render that component there? If not, then how can that be achieved. I was under the impression that it already is inside the return function

Comment: `{dropDownValue && <WardNo dropDownValue={dropDownValue}></WardNo>}`. This ensures that if `dropDownValue` is not null then only render `Ward Component`

Comment: Brilliant. And where exactly should I be putting this line?

Comment: Inside return function of `SearchBox Component`

Comment: Doesn't work. These boxes render all over again besides the ones that were already there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `WardNo` component when you are filtering you just mentioned `value.district === props`. It should be `props.dropDownValue`. Because `props` is an object which contains `dropDownValue`.

And when you are rendering the dropdown option inside `WardNo` component you don't need two `map`. You can use `filteredData[0].ward_no.map(...`

Updated WardNo Component

```
const WardNo = (props) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [wardNumber, setWardNumber] = useState(null);
  const filteredData = data.filter((value) => value.district === props.dropDownValue); 

  const onSelect = (value) => {
    setWardNumber(value);
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  return (
    <div className="ward_no">
      {props.dropDownValue}
      <div className="ward_caption">Ward No</div>
      <div className="ward_block">
        <div className="ward_dropdown">
          <div className="ward_box">
            {wardNumber === null ? "Enter Ward Number" : wardNumber}
          </div>
          <div
            className="ward_dropIcon"
            onClick={() => setOpen((prev) => !prev)}
          >
            {open ? (
              <GoTriangleUp size={"25px"} />
            ) : (
              <IoMdArrowDropdown size={"30px"} />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={open ? "ward_option" : "ward_option_block"}>
          {filteredData[0].ward_no.map((ward_value, ward_key) => (
              <div
                className="ward_options"
                key={ward_key}
                onClick={() => onSelect(ward_value.ward)}
              >
                {ward_value.ward}
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```